# Can I divide the disk which has linux installed

Tags: linux, debian, dual-boot, grub, debian-installer

I have 2TB disk and I partitioned disk into 2 file systems. 1TB is NTFS to be used by windows which is booting from SSD.
The other 1TB I am setting it as ext4 and installing linux.
Do you think any errors will occur?
Is NTFS partition will make a corrupted installation for linux?

Comment: Is Windows UEFI on gpt partitioned drive? Is then 2TB drive gpt? Ubuntu's Ubiquity installer only installs to ESP on first drive. Other Linux may give you a choice to have ESP on Linux drive. If Ubuntu or any flavor of Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1296065/dual-booting-w10-ubuntu-with-2-separate-ssds-in-uefi-mode/1296153#1296153

Answer (score 0):

No, errors should not occur as a result of having NTFS on the same drive as your Linux installation. NTFS is a Windows-specific file system and typically does not interfere with the Linux installation process.